# Jackson ignore empty string value in collection when deserializing

Tags: java, jackson, java-8

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "terms": ["Hello", "", "World"]
}
```

and this POJO:

```
@JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)
public class Query {
    public List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want to ignore empty string at deserialization. (Load only `"Hello" and "World"`)

```
public class EmptyStringValueInList {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper();
        Query query = mapper.readValue("{\"terms\": [\"Hello\", \"\", \"World\"]}", Query.class);
        System.out.println(query.terms.size()); // print 3, I expect 2
    }
}
```

I tried several configurations but nothings works.

Comment: Have you tried using `@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)`? Starting from version 2.x, they changes the syntax.

Comment: I highly doubt that you will find such feature, it seems like very uncommon case to remove values from the middle of an array.

Comment: @1615903 may be i should extend a serializer but i didn't find anything

Comment: This might be useful: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers